# String erase-append

Tags: c++, string

So generally I am supposed to take a few first characters of a string and put them on the end of this string. To make it simple, let's say - first two characters. I tried something like this:

```
char a = mystring.at(0);
char b = mystring.at(1);
mystring.erase(0,1);
mystring.append(a);
mystring.append(b);
```

This of course gives an error converting from char to string. However, I have no idea how to do it, what other functions to use. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of mystring? Is it a std::string?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the algorithm [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
  std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 2, s.end());
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
CDEFGHIJAB
```

Comment: I am getting a 'string operator+ offset out of range" error

Comment: @krmtb Then you're doing something else wrong. The code I posted works.